# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable when using reduce and lambda

Tags: python, function, functional-programming

```
from functools import reduce

lists = [lambda x: x+5, lambda x: x+6, lambda x: x+7]
n = 5

print(list(reduce(lambda a, b: a(n) + b(n), lists)))
```

I am not sure why I am getting the error "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? Do you know what ``reduce`` actually does? In specific, what type/value do you expect ``a`` to be on each step?

Comment: I expected it to use the lambda function that is in lists[]. I thought the final result should print 23

Comment: But `a(n) + b(n)` will return *an `int` object*, which gets passed to the next iteration as `a`... so when you do `some_int(n) + b(n)`.... you get the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are both functions, but only `b` is guaranteed to be a function from the list argument. `a` is the *result* of the last call to  of the previous call to the first argument to `reduce`. You want to reduce `lists` using function composition.

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: lambda n: b(a(n)), lists)(5)
23
```

(In this particular case, `a(b(n))` would work the same, because all three functions involved the same commutative operation, so the composition is commutative as well. In general, though, `a` is bound to the first function and `b` the second on the first iteration; after that, `a` is bound to the result and `b` bound to the next function from the list.)

To make it work with an empty list, you need to supply the identity function (`lambda x: x`) as the initial value, as that is the identity for function composition:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: lambda n: b(a(n)), [])(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: reduce() of empty sequence with no initial value
>>> reduce(lambda a, b: lambda n: b(a(n)), [], lambda x: x)(5)
5
```

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` uses the previous result of calling the function as one of the inputs to the next invocation.  The function returns an `int` the first time you call it, so the second time you call it its two arguments are that int and another function -- and an int isn't a valid parameter for the reducing function you've provided (it expects two functions), so you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply an initial value to `reduce` and accumulate other values later.

```
reduce(lambda acc, b: acc + b(n), lists, 0)
```

Alternative, we can split this into two operations: a `map` and a `reduce`.

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, map(lambda f: f(n), lists), 0)
```

`reduce` with `+` and `0` is just `sum`, so we can shorten this to

```
sum(map(lambda f: f(n), lists))
```

or, equivalently

```
sum(f(n) for f in lists)
```

Comment: reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, map(lambda f: f(n), lists)) doesnt result in an error but it still doesn't return the right number

Comment: The question phrased in the OP involves adding the results together. If that's not the desired behavior, please edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: We do want to add the results together, but in the OP the result should be 23, but using your code it returns 33

Comment: If you expect 23, then you do *not* want to add the results together. You want function composition, and go read chepner's answer.